# array_diff() on arrays of arrays return wrong results

Tags: php

My understanding of `array_diff()`, is that the following code must return `array($a[1])`.

This is not the behavior. Instead, an `array()` returned.

What I understand wrong?

```
<?php
$a = array(
    array('contract' => '5/1-4-2019'),
    array('contract' => '1/1-4-2019'));
$b = array($a[0]);
var_dump(array_diff($a, $b));
?>
```

Comment: array_diff() returns a new array, you're not catching the return value anywhere

Comment: (PHP Version permitting) you can try `var_dump(array_udiff($a, $b, function($a, $b) { return $a['contract'] <=> $b['contract'];}));`

Comment: Console catching it via var_dump()

Comment: @Nigel Ren My arrays, in sample, are simplified. The question is why `array_diff()` evaluates `$a[1]===$b[0]` as `true`

Comment: The problem is that it `array_diff` doesn't work with multidimensional arrays properly.

Comment: Based on @NigelRen answer `var_dump(array_udiff($a, $b, function($a, $b) { return $a <=> $b; }));`